# DiscordAPIError: Missing Access

Tags: discord, discord.js

When I start my discord bot that happens to me, which is what I have to do

This is a screenshot of the cmd
[image]

Comment: Can you show us some of your code or tell what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64217395/discordapierror-missing-access-on-createoverwrite

Comment: @navnath if you look at the path you will see they are trying to either make, or edit slash commands

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that you're trying to create a command in a guild where you don't have the permissions to create slash commands.

Try inviting your bot again with this invite link: https://discord.com/oauth2/authorize?client_id=YOUR-CLIENT-ID&scope=applications.commands+bot&permissions=8